# Is following refactoring proper according to redux no mutation standard?

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I understand users may downvote my question, but I need to be sure, and I have no way of being sure, unless I ask react redux experienced person. Please answer and not downvote.
 question is it ok to refactor the code as shown below, or there may arise some issue

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { 
      router,
      classDetail,
      categories,
      instructorFreeSlots
     } = state;

  return {
    router,
    classDetail,
    categories,
    instructorFreeSlots
  };
};


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  state.router,
  state.classDetail,
  state.categories,
  state.instructorFreeSlots,
})
```

common code is:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  dispatch,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ClassDetailContainer);
```

Comment: in the first example, is the `mapDispatchToProps ` a typo? shouldn't it be `mapStateToProps`? As for you question there is no difference regarding mutations in JavaScript. its just using destructuring vs not using it.

Comment: ya corrected that code

Comment: No, this is invalid syntax. Did you try it?

Comment: @AkshayVijayJain can you please check my answer? If you have any other related questions, please leave me a comment below the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your refactoring improvements are not related to any data mutations. Let's review them:

## 1. `mapStateToProps` refactoring:

Your `mapStateToProps` refactoring regarding to [Object Initializer and Shorthand property naming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and it's syntactically incorrect. It can be:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ router, classDetail, categories, instructorFreeSlots }) => ({ 
  router, classDetail, categories, instructorFreeSlots
})
```

Also your first version is perfectly fine too. Here we mainly talk about syntactic sugar, so we shouldn't be worried to much. Choose your convention and stick with it.

## 2. `mapDispatchToProps` refactoring:

According to your use-case (where nothing is added to), you can omit passing the `mapDispatchToProps` function to the `connect` function and the `dispatch` function will be passed automatically to your `ClassDetailContainer`:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ClassDetailContainer)
```

Keep in mind that if you pass down `mapDispatchToProps` to the `connect`, `mapDispatchToProps` can be an Object or a Function.

Please check [`mapDispatchToProps` official documentation](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) for better understanding how it works, but here is the main idea:

> **If an object is passed**, each function inside it is assumed to be a Redux action creator. An object with the same function names, but with
> every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so they may be
> invoked directly, will be merged into the component’s props.
>
> **If a function is passed**, it will be given dispatch as the first parameter. It’s up to you to return an object that somehow uses
> dispatch to bind action creators in your own way. (Tip: you may use
> the bindActionCreators() helper from Redux.)